# Best GridFS C# driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, gridfs

What is the best realization of GridFS C# driver? What is your experience?

**Update:**

When i say "best" - i mean stability.

Thank you!!!

Comment: When you say best realization, what exactly do you mean? Ease of use, performance, feature support?

Comment: @Justin thank you! I mean no leaking memory, minimum bugs, nice connection-exception handling etc. As i found samus driver sometimes blocks connections to MongoDB if something was wrong while adding new file, so i need to restart database. But maybe driver is ok and i made very fast tests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using [official mongodb driver](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial) and it work perfect for me.

If you want you can check [how to save and read back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988436/mongodb-gridfs-with-c-how-to-store-files-such-as-images/4990536#4990536) file using official c# driver.

Comment: @Howard: just fyi: i am currently using gridfs in one my project i really like how it work, in additional in latest mongovue was added better gridfs support.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the official driver and it seems to work well.

I tried using the [mongodb-csharp](https://github.com/samus/mongodb-csharp) driver from Sam Corder but never could get GridFS to work properly (though, it is a great driver for LINQ style queries, etc).