# Using GridFS with official C# driver in MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, mongodb, monodevelop, mongodb-.net-driver, freebsd

I am using MonoDevelop on PC-BSD 10.1 and working with MongoDB 3.2. I downloaded MongoDB.Driver (+Bson& Core) from Nuget. I can do basic reads and writes and was trying to get GridFS working by following what seems to be the most current example from StackOverflow:

[MongoDB GridFs with C#, how to store files such as images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988436/mongodb-gridfs-with-c-how-to-store-files-such-as-images/4990536#4990536)

First, my system doesn't recognize the (seemingly) static MongoServer class, so I switch to MognoClient to get a database. Then I get the following:

"Type `MongoDB.Driver.IMongoDatabase' does not contain a definition for`GridFS' and no extension method `GridFS' of type`MongoDB.Driver.IMongoDatabase' could be found. "

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using MongoDB;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Driver.Core;
using MongoDB.Bson;
//using MongoDB.Driver.GridFS; -> an attempt to use the legacy driver.


namespace OIS.Objektiv.SocketServer
{
    public class Gridfs
    {
        public Gridfs ()
        {

            var server = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://localhost:27017");
            var database = server.GetDatabase("test");

//          var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
//          var database = client.GetDatabase("test");

            var fileName = "D:\\Untitled.png";
            var newFileName = "D:\\new_Untitled.png";
            using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
            {
                var gridFsInfo = database.GridFS.Upload(fs, fileName);
                var fileId = gridFsInfo.Id;

                ObjectId oid= new ObjectId(fileId);
                var file = database.GridFS.FindOne(Query.EQ("_id", oid));

                using (var stream = file.OpenRead())
                {
                    var bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
                    stream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);
                    using(var newFs = new FileStream(newFileName, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        newFs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What stupid error have I done? Does GridFS have a dependency I'm missing? This should work! :(

Dinsdale

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have downloaded the 2.0 version of the driver. It currently does not have a GridFS API. You can track that feature here(https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1191). In addition, MongoServer is gone in the 2.0 API.

However, there is a wrapper for the legacy API available available if you pull the mongocsharpdriver nuget package. With that, you'll have both MongoServer and GridFS.

Comment: How can use this wrapper?

Comment: To use old API you have to get MongoServer from MongoClient and then get MongoDatabase from MongoServer. If you get MongoDatabase directly from MongoClient you will be using new API.

Answer (score 13):

With driver version 2.2 you have do download a separate NuGet package called `MongoDB.Driver.GridFS`.

You can use it this way:

```
IMongoDatabase database;

var bucket = new GridFSBucket(database, new GridFSOptions
{
    BucketName = "videos",
    ChunkSizeBytes = 1048576, // 1MB
    WriteConcern = WriteConcern.Majority,
    ReadPreference = ReadPeference.Secondary
}); 

IGridFSBucket bucket;
bytes[] source;
var options = new GridFSUploadOptions
{
    ChunkSizeBytes = 64512, // 63KB
    Metadata = new BsonDocument
    {
        { "resolution", "1080P" },
        { "copyrighted", true }
    } 
};  

var id = bucket.UploadFromBytes("filename", source, options);
```

[Here the full doc](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/reference/gridfs/).

Comment: Great answer, should be the answer for the question too!

Comment: I agree with you! :)