# How to retrieve and display an image which is stored in Mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb, visual-studio

I'm implementing an application using C# in Visual Studio.I tried to retrieve data which are already in Mongodb.I retrieved some values but I don't know how to get an image which is in fs.files collection using GridFS.I need to display the retrieved image in a picture box of my application.

[image]

Here is the structure of fs.files collection in mongodb.

Can anyone please explain this?

Thank You

Comment: Is the "picture" stored as a byte array in mongodb? I've never used mongodb before, but however you retrieve it, you may just need to convert from a byte array to an image type in the c# code to be able to display it in your picture box.

Comment: Also, this question seems highly relevant from the sidebar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988436/mongodb-gridfs-with-c-how-to-store-files-such-as-images?rq=1

Comment: Yap..Thanks..I already followed that way.But I was stuck on show the image in a picture box. Anyway I solved it..Thanks for your advice.

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer to your own question, and if other people find your question and answer and it helps them, they may upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution.

var fileName = @"D:CDAP\myfunction\ruwanwelimahaseya.jpg";//image which I want to save in the database
var newFileName = @"D:CDAP\myfunction\new.jpg";

```
        using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var gridFsInfo = DB.GridFS.Upload(fs, fileName);
            var fileId = gridFsInfo.Id;

            ObjectId oid = new ObjectId(fileId.ToString());
            var file = DB.GridFS.FindOne(Query.EQ("_id", oid));


            using (var stream = file.OpenRead())
            {
                var bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);
                using (var newFs = new FileStream(newFileName, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    newFs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    Image image = Image.FromStream(newFs);

                    f2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

                    f2.Image = image;

                }
            }
        }
```